# How to evaluate the result of the noexcept() operator

Tags: c++, noexcept

For example,

```
template<class T,size_t N>
void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a,*b)));
```

Under what condition will the function can, or cannot, throw an exception?

Answer (score 2):

```
noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a,*b)))
```

The outer one is the [noexcept specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), the inner one is the [noexcept operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept).

It's `noexcept`, if `swap` for `T`s is `noexcept`.

That it's, it can only throw if that swap can throw.

Answer (score 2):

quick explanation:

the inner `noexcept` returns `true` if the function `swap(T&, T&)` is marked `noexcept`.

the outer `noexcept` marks this function as `noexcept` if the inner `noexcept` returns true.

Therefore, this function copies the `noexcept` semantics of `swap(T&, T&)`.